# If design matrices $X$, $Y$ are close to each other, are their projection matrices also close?

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space, projection, projection-matrices

Let $A, B$ be two $m\times n$ matrices with $n > m$ and full row-rank. Define the following two (projection) matrices
$$
\begin{align}
    P_A &= A^\top(AA^\top)^{-1}A \\
    P_B &= B^\top(BB^\top)^{-1}B.
\end{align}
$$

> Intuitively, if $A$ and $B$ are similar, does this mean $P_A$ and $P_B$ are similar?

For instance, let $\epsilon > 0$ be small, and assume $\|A - B\|_I < \epsilon$. Can I say $\|P_A - P_B\|_I < \epsilon$, or something along those lines?

Comment: Usually similarity means that there is some $P$ such that $PBP^{-1}=A$ and it can only be formulated for square matrices. What does it mean here for two rectangular matrices to be similar? And is it the same similarity for $P_A$ and $P_B$?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio you raise a good point, I have been imprecise with my wording. This is what I mean: I know that $A$ and $B$ are close to being the same matrix, for instance $\|A - B\|_I < \epsilon$, where $\epsilon > 0$ is a small tolerance and $\|\cdot\|_I$ is the induced norm (could use another norm if necessary). Given that this is true, can I say the projection matrices are close too?

Comment: The matrix $P_A$ projects onto the range of $A^T$, right? An projection operators always have norm $\ge 1$ (if they are not the zero map), so I'd think that your statement does not hold in general, since operator norm greater than 1 should mean intuitively, that the maps enlarges distance, right?

Comment: @Ramanujan [Any orthogonal projection is bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Properties_and_special_cases) meaning $\|P_A x\| \leq \|x\|$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then this means
$$
\|P_A\|_I := \sup_{x\neq 0} \frac{\|P_A x\|}{\|x\|} \leq 1.
$$
Unless I am missing something

Comment: Orthogonal projections have operator norm equal to 1, the non-orthogonal ones $> 1$. Is the projection $P_A$ orthogonal?

Comment: @Ramanujan Yes, I think $P_A$ is an orthogonal projection because
$$
\langle P_A x, y \rangle = x^\top P_A^\top y = x^\top P_A y = \langle x, P_A y\rangle
$$

Comment: @Ramanujan oh of course the operator norm is equal to one, because if $x$ belongs to the column space of $A$ then $\|P_A x\| = \|x\|$

Comment: @Ramanujan I meant if $x$ belongs to the row space of $A$

Comment: @Euler By a certain interpretation of your question, the answer is "yes because the function $f(X) = X^T(XX^T)^{-1}X$ is **continuous** over the set of full rank $m \times n$ matrices". Maybe that helps.

Comment: @Euler In other words, for any $A$ and for any $\epsilon > 0$, you can guarantee that $\|P_A - P_B\| < \epsilon$ by ensuring that $B$ is sufficiently close to $A$. I suspect that how close $B$ needs to be to $A$ depends on the condition number of $A^T$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks! Is it a standard result that that function is continuous over the set of full rank $m\times n$ matrices?

Comment: @Euler_Salter No, but it is the consequence of a few standard results together. We can think of $f$ as being a composition $f = f_1 \circ f_2 \circ f_3$ of the functions $f_1(A,B,C) = ABC$, $f_2(A,B,C) = (A,B^{-1},C)$, $f_3(A) = (A,A^TA,A^T)$. It is a "standard" fact that $f_1$ is continuous, that the component functions of $f_2,f_3$ (hence the functions themselves) are continuous, and that the composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Aah I see. So do you think it would be possible to say that $f(X) = X^\top(XX^\top)^{-1} X$ is Lipschitz continuous? Perhaps
$$
\|f(X) - f(Y)\| \leq L \|X - Y\|
$$
where the Lipschitz constant depends on the condition numbers?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the Lipschitz constant depends on the condition numbers". Lipschitz means that $\|f(X) - f(Y)\| \leq L\|X - Y\|$, where $L$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$. No such constant exists, so no: this function is not Lipschitz.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I didn't word it properly. Basically I mean it in the context of this other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4556447/when-is-the-projection-mathrmpx-longmapsto-mathrmjx-top-mathrmjx