# When is the projection $\mathrm{P}:x\longmapsto \mathrm{J}(x)^\top(\mathrm{J}(x)\mathrm{J}(x)^\top)^{-1}\mathrm{J}(x)$ Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

- $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a smooth function with $n > m$.
- $\mathrm{J}(x)$ is the Jacobian matrix of $f$ and it is full row-rank at every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
- For any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ define the projection matrix as the $n\times n$ symmetric idempotent matrix
  $$
  \mathrm{P}(x) = \mathrm{J}(x)^\top(\mathrm{J}(x)\mathrm{J}(x)^\top)^{-1}\mathrm{J}(x).
  $$

> Can I say that $\mathrm{P}: x\longmapsto \mathrm{P}(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous? If not, what conditions do I need to say this?

Comment: Why do you call that a "projection"? Where does it project to?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro It's the orthogonal projection onto the row space of $J(x)$

Comment: @Euler_Slater I suspect that this function is Lipschitz if there exists a global bound on the condition number of $J(x)$, but for a general smooth function $f$ probably not

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Basically $\mathrm{J}(x)$ decomposes the space into the orthogonal product $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathcal{N}_x \oplus \mathcal{R}_x$, where $\mathcal{N}_x$ is the null space and $\mathcal{R}_x$ is the row space of $\mathrm{J}(x)$

Comment: @BenGrossmann how do you arrive at that conclusion on the condition number?

Comment: @Euler I don't understand your question. I think you're asking "how do you prove the result given the additional assumption about the condition number", is that correct?

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, exactly! Or more broadly: what additional assumptions do I need to have Lipschitz continuity? I would even just be happy with simply bounding the difference when the inputs are close (similar to my other question)

Comment: @BenGrossmann basically if $y=x+\epsilon$ then I would like to be able to say something about $\|P(x)-P(y)\|$

Comment: @Euler_Slater Here's the approach I had in mind:
$$
\|P(y) - P(x)\| = \\
\|\mathrm{J}(y)^\top(\mathrm{J}(y)\mathrm{J}(y)^\top)^{-1}\mathrm{J}(y) -
\mathrm{J}(x)^\top(\mathrm{J}(x)\mathrm{J}(x)^\top)^{-1}\mathrm{J}(x)\|\leq\\
\|(\mathrm{J}(x)\mathrm{J}(x)^\top)^{-1}\mathrm{J}(x)\| \cdot \|\mathrm{J}(x) - \mathrm J(y)\|
\\ + \|(\mathrm{J}(x)\mathrm{J}(x)^\top)^{-1} - (\mathrm{J}(y)\mathrm{J}(y)^\top)^{-1}\| \cdot \|\mathrm{J}(x)\|\cdot \|\mathrm{J}(y)\|\\
+ \|(\mathrm{J}(y)\mathrm{J}(y)^\top)^{-1}\mathrm{J}(y)\| \cdot \|\mathrm{J}(x) - \mathrm J(y)\|
$$

Comment: From there, you could probably bound the terms separately. The condition number would be important for bounding the second term. For the first and third term, one might be able to make use of the properties of the Moore Penrose psuedoinverse, namely $A^+ = A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$ (for $A$ of full row rank). I'm having trouble making this work, though.

Comment: Another potentially useful thought is that $P(x)$ is effectively a smooth map to the [Grassmannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) $\mathrm{Gr}(m,n)$

Comment: I think my condition number assumption is insufficient; we might also need a bound on $\|J(x)\|$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann How did you find the inequality in the display above?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I recall that $\text{cond}(J(x)) = \|J(x)\| \|J(x)^+\|$ so if the condition number is bounded you should get a bound on $\|J(x)\|$ too I think

Comment: @Euler_Salter That's only true if $\|J(x)^+\|$ has a global lower bound

Comment: @Euler_Salter Regarding the inequality, I did something like this:
$$
\|A_1A_2A_3 - B_1B_2B_3\| = \\
\|(A_1 - B_1)A_2A_3 + B_1(A_2-B_2)A_3 + B_1B_2(A_3-B_3)\| \leq\\
\|(A_1 - B_1)A_2A_3\| + \|B_1(A_2-B_2)A_3\| + \|B_1B_2(A_3-B_3)\|
$$

Comment: $P$ doesn't have to be globally Lipschitz. Take $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y) = y + \sin(x^2)$. Then $J(x,y) = [2x \cos(x^2)\ \ \ \ 1]$ so the upper left entry of $P$ is $\tfrac{4 x^2 \cos^2(x^2)}{4x^2 \cos^2(x^2)+1}$. As $x$ goes from $\sqrt{\pi N}$ to $\sqrt{\pi (N+1/2)}$, a change of roughly $N^{-1/2}$, the function $\tfrac{4 x^2 \cos^2(x^2)}{4x^2 \cos^2(x^2)+1}$ changes from almost $1$ to $0$. Is this the sort of counter-example you would accept, or did you only want locally Lipschitz?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I am actually just interested in knowing which conditions I could ask of $f$ in order to obtain global lipschitz continuity. I am aware not all smooth $f$ will be. I am asking what are some possible sufficient conditions?

Answer (score 1):

In general the map $P:x\mapsto P(x)$ is not globally Lipschitz continuous, as @David E Speyer showed in the comments.

Since you are interested in sufficient conditions, here is a set. As usual with sufficient conditions, they are a little strong.

###### Theorem

Let $J$ be such that

1. $J(x)$ is bounded by $C$
2. $J^\dagger(x)$ is bounded by $C_\dagger$
3. $x\mapsto J(x)$ is Lipschitz with $Lip_J$
4. $x\mapsto J^\dagger(x)$ is Lipschitz with $Lip_{J^\dagger}$

where $J^\dagger(x) = J^\intercal(x)\bigg(J(x)J^\intercal(x)\bigg)^{-1}$. Then
$$
  Lip_P \leq Lip_{J^\dagger}C+Lip_{J}C_{\dagger}.
$$

###### Proof

This follows from
$$
   \|P(x)-P(y)\| = \|J^\dagger(x)J(x)-J^\dagger(y)J(y)\| \\ 
\leq \|J^\dagger(x)J(x)-J^\dagger(x)J(y)\|+\|J^\dagger(x)J(y)-J^\dagger(y)J(y)\| \\
\leq \|J^\dagger(x)\|\|J(x)-J(y)\|+\|J^\dagger(x)J(y)-J^\dagger(y)J(y)\|.
$$
The first term can be bounded using the boundedness assumption on $J^\dagger$ and the Lipschitz continuity of $J$ by
$$
\|J^\dagger(x)\|\|J(x)-J(y)\| \leq C_{\dagger}Lip_J\|x-y\|.
$$
The second term can be bounded by the remaining two conditions by
$$
\|J^\dagger(x)J(y)-J^\dagger(y)J(y)\| = \sup_{\|z\|=1}\|J^\dagger(x)J(y)z-J^\dagger(y)J(y)z\| \\ \leq \sup_{\|z\|=1}\|J^\dagger(x)-J^\dagger(y)\|\|J(y)z\|\
\\ \leq Lip_{J^\dagger}\sup_{\|z\|=1}\|J(y)z\|\|x-y\| \\
= Lip_{J^\dagger}\|J(y)\|\|x-y\|.
$$
Hence,
$$
\|P(x)-P(y)\| \leq (Lip_{J^\dagger}C+Lip_{J}C_{\dagger})\|x-y\|.
$$

###### QED

Observe that $cond(J(x)) = \|J(x)\|\|J^\dagger(x)\| \leq C_{\dagger}C$. This can help to reduce the strength of the assumptions on $J$ or $J^\dagger$.